# How do you configure protobuf-net's RuntimeModel.Default to support serializing/deserializing a SessionSecurityToken?

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-4.5, protobuf-net

BinaryFormatter is able to handle serialization simply:

```
private byte[] TokenToBytes(SessionSecurityToken token)
{
    if (token == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, token);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

When I tried replacing BinaryFormatter with protobuf-net:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, token);
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

I get the following exception:

> Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred:
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityToken

I tried adding:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(SessionSecurityToken), true);
```

Which gets past the exception but I now get a zero byte array.

**How do I properly configure protobuf-net to serialize a SessionSecurityToken?**

On the flipside, SessionSecurityToken does not have a parameterless constructor.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(tokenAsBytes))
{
    return Serializer.Deserialize<SessionSecurityToken>(memoryStream);
}
```

Throws a ProtoException:

> No parameterless constructor found for SessionSecurityToken

`BinaryFormatter` is able to do it without any fuss:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    return (SessionSecurityToken)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
}
```

**How do I properly configure protobuf-net to deserialize a SessionSecurityToken?**

Comment: You are unable to serialize the SessionSecurityToken using protobuf cause it inherits SecurityToken which is not serializable. could you please tell me that can you convert SessionSecurityToken to some other type like byte[] or some generic type and can get back SessionSecurityToken form converted type? then i can give you a solution. @DPeden

Comment: can you create a new custom class with the member of SessionSecurityToken that can take all the necessary data from SessionSecurityToken members?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, with another type - but the same exact problem - did you ever solve this?

Comment: I stayed with BinaryFormatter as it worked and, as Marc mentioned in his last sentence, it wasn't worth it to jump through the hoops since this was the only thing I was serializing, not a larger model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

protobuf-net does not claim to be able to serialize every single type; indeed, you would have great difficulty serializing that via most serializers (`XmlSerializer`, any of the json serializers, `DataContractSerializer`, etc). `BinaryFormatter` is in a different *category* of serializers - and in this particular case, implements custom serialization via `ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)`.

The constructor thing is a red herring; actually, protobuf-net can bypass constructors completely, and in this particular scenario `BinaryFormatter` is using a custom serialization constructor via `.ctor(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)`.

For simple cases, protobuf-net can be configured via attributes or runtime options; for more complex scenarios, *surrogates* can be used to map between representations - however, in this case I would suggest (looking at the implementation of `SessionSecurityToken`) that this is more complex than you probably want to maintain.

I would step back a step or two here; most serializers are designed to work with *data*, not implementation - and work great with DTOs etc. `SessionSecurityToken` is very much **not** a DTO, and there is no simple way of switching between them. My strong suggestion here would be: serialize what this *represents*, not what it *is*. However, if this is part of an existing complex model and is really really hard to separate out, you could switch back to `BinaryFormatter` for those bits. I haven't tested this, but consider:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(SessionSecurityToken), false)
        .SetSurrogate(typeof(BinaryFormatterSurrogate<SessionSecurityToken>));
```

With:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class BinaryFormatterSurrogate<T>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public byte[] Raw { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator T(BinaryFormatterSurrogate<T> value)
    {
        if(value==null || value.Raw == null) return default(T);
        using(var ms = new MemoryStream(value.Raw))
        {
            return (T)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }
    public static explicit operator BinaryFormatterSurrogate<T>(T value)
    {
        object obj = value;
        if (obj == null) return null;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(ms, obj);
            return new BinaryFormatterSurrogate<T> { Raw = ms.ToArray() };
        }

    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this simply embeds the output of one serializer as raw data inside another. Fortunately protobuf-net is happy talking binary, so this won't add any noticeable overhead (just the header and length-prefix for the blob) - but it also won't do anything particularly smart or clever with the `SessionSecurityToken` instances. If this is the *only* thing you are serializing, it really isn't worth it. If this is just one ugly bump in a larger DTO model, where most of it *can* serialize nicely - then it might get the job done for you.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond with some sample code.  I was unable to look at this for about a week.  Sorry for the slow response.

Comment: Marc where do you put the calls to RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add. Would you put them in the object constructor or in a static constructor for the entire project? Secondly what is the difference between ProtoBufFormatter.Model vs RuntimeTypeModel,Default. Is one for WebAPI and one is for the other nuget package?